# In JSP, want to use pageContext.forward and process the result

Tags: jsp, process, single-sign-on, token, forward

I'm trying to inject a JSP page into an unnamed enterprise web-application to get the value of a SSO token provided by a servlet. The goal is to redirect back to the referrer. The user does not have to enter any logon information, as this is done with Kerberos and the negotiate header of the http request.

The approach i'm taking now is using

```
    pageContext.forward("logon");
```

to have the request forwarded to the logon servlet and get the token, but am at a loss as to what to do after this.

The token is in the form of CDATA inside a  element. I need to do some processing on the result of my forward before returning to the referrer, but am at a loss as to how. Any help would be appreciated.